# How do I calculate angle from roll in landscape mode for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, landscape, angle, motion

So, I've been testing the sensors API for Windows Phone 8. For my app I use the Combined Motion (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202984(v=vs.105).aspx).

Everything works fine while in Portrait mode, I convert the roll parameter (I skip yaw and pitch) to degrees, and I can print out the angle in degrees on screen. If I hold the phone in front of me and rotate it counter clockwise, I see the degrees going from 0 to -20, -30 and so on.

However, when I flip it to landscape mode, I get the wrong angle. After doing a bit of reading up on the yaw, pitch and roll in general (read: airplanes), and how it is applied on phones (Android, WP), I realise that the roll angle is only to be trusted in the range [-90,90] degrees. After printing out the roll values, this is what I see, which confirms the range (tap link to show image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPqG1.png)

So that means I can't differentiate between -45 degrees and -135 degrees, as the roll value is the same.

So, my question is: what do I have to do to get my app to print the absolute angle (from 0-360), as I turn it clockwise (or counter clockwise)?

Surely there must be a way to determine (in landscape mode) if the phone is held parallel with the floor?

I'm using VS2012/C#/Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Any pointers in the right direction is appreciated, perhaps I need to brush up on my high school math?

Comment: Have you come up with a solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes, have a look at this starter kit from MS: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/sample/level_starter_kit

Answer (score 0):

To determine the Portrait/Landscape orientation you can use the OrientationChanged event on the page.

First at page initialization determine the orientation:

```
private PageOrientation lastOrientation;

// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lastOrientation = this.Orientation;

    if ((lastOrientation == PageOrientation.Landscape) ||
        (lastOrientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft) ||
        (lastOrientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight))
    {
         DoLandscapeCalculation();
    }
    else if ((lastOrientation == PageOrientation.Portrait) ||
             (lastOrientation == PageOrientation.PortraitDown) ||
             (lastOrientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp))
    {
         DoPortraitCalculation();
    }

    ...
```

Then register for the OrientationChanged event and act accordingly:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if ((e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape) ||
        (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft) ||
        (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight))
    {
        //Landscape
        DoLandscapeCalculation();
    }
    else if ((e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Portrait) ||
             (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp) ||
             (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitDown))
    {
         //Portrait
         DoPortraitCalculation();
    }

    // Extra work here!

    ...

    lastOrientation = e.Orientation;
}
```

Hope this is a start for you.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks vidonism, I am well aware of the Orientation event. My question concerns the content of the methods you call DoPortraitCalculation() and DoLandscapeCalculation(). The roll values I get from the Motion API doesn't change, they are the same, regardless of Orientation.